# Random image using glob

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to get a random image from a dir and every time it returns an error "Warning: Undefined array key 0

```
$randomImage = call_user_func(function(){
    return function() {
        $i = glob('../assets/spaces/*'); 
        shuffle($i);
        return $i[0];
    };
});
```

If I run the script like this it returns 1000 random images without an issue, when I call it on a page I get the error.  Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++){
echo $randomImage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: The `glob()` function *can* return an empty array if no match was found, and thus `$i[0]` would produce a warning. In addition it can return `false` which will lead to the same result. See the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php and place some conditional logic in your function before attempting to work on `$i`.

Comment: Are you coming from Javascript? Why not simply write: `function randomImage() { .... }` and then call it like so: `echo randomImage() . "\n";`. There must be a very special reason you need a variable function there... The whole code is just a bit weird.

Comment: `when I call it on a page I get the error` ... is likely a relative path issue coupled with that you are not checking `$i` for empty array and false inside your function after your `glob()` call.

Comment: There is no need for this : `call_user_func()` and this `return function()` when You can simply `$randomImage = function(){$i ...... };`  Try adding `array_values($i)[0];` to reset the array keys.  Or simply `array_shift()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

It's possible `$i` is empty - in which case it would be `false`

```
$randomImage =  function() {
    $i = glob('../assets/spaces/*'); 
    shuffle($i);
    return $i ? array_shift($i) : false;  // get the first element of the array
};
```

Comment: Sure, it was a simple one.